# How to get GPS Coordinates out of String (Python)

Tags: python, string

for my new pyhton project I need to get coordinates out of a string.

my actual code looks like this:

```
import exifread
from selenium import webdriver

with open("pictures/img-1.jpg", "rb") as file:
    tags = exifread.process_file(file)

    for key, value in tags.items():
               
        gesamtzeile = str(key) + ": " + str(value)
        print(gesamtzeile)
```

in the variable "gesamtzeile" there are outputs like:

```
Image YResolution: 72
```

OR  LIKE:

```
GPS GPSLatitude: [28, 12, 1857/50]
```

etc.....

Now i want to check in the loop if the string(key) contains the word "GPS". If it contains "GPS", I want to filter the coordinates.

Can somebody please help me? I am new to python and don't get it at the moment;/

Thanks a lot

I tried to use "split" and tried to split it at ":" but I only want to split if the string contains "GPS".I don't know how to do this in python

Comment: when I use the "in" method in python I should be able to get only the strings which contain "GPS".
is that true till this point?

But how can i seperate the coordinates?

Comment: Don't combine them  into a string like that.  Just do something like `if key.startswith('GPS'):`.  Next, is `value` actually a string?  Or is it a list, like the output implies?  If it's a list of integers, then the job is easy, right?

Comment: How is the question related to Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

The `exifread` module returns these values in custom types.  You just need to fetch the values:

```
import exifread

with open("pictures/img-1.jpg", "rb") as file:
    tags = exifread.process_file(file)
    if "GPS GPSLatitude" in tags:
        l1 = tags["GPS GPSLatitude"].values
        # Now l1[0] is degrees, l1[1]is minutes, and
        # l1[2] is seconds as a ratio.
        print( "lat", li[0], "degrees", li[1], "minutes", float(li[2]), "seconds" )
    elif "GPS GPSLongitude" in tags:
        l1 = tags["GPS GPSLongitude"].values
        print( "long", li[0], "degrees", li[1], "minutes", float(li[2]), "seconds" )
```

Comment: thanks, that worked fine for me.

new issue is, that in the "li[0]" is an "spacekey".
Do you know how I can delete those spacekeys?

Comment: I don't know what you mean,  `li[0]` is an ordinary integer.  It doesn't have any spaces.  I think you are confusing the VALUE of the field with your PRESENTATION of the field.

Comment: yea, if I print "li[0]", then there is for example: "8 " 
So behind the value there is an space, i cant work with this if it contains the space.

this is the code:

`if "GPS GPSLatitude" in tags:
        l1 = tags["GPS GPSLatitude"].values
        print(l1[0], "°", l1[1], "'",float(l1[2]), "\"N")
    if "GPS GPSLongitude" in tags:
        l1 = tags["GPS GPSLongitude"].values
        print(l1[0], "°", l1[1], "'", float(l1[2]), "\"W")`


and this is the output with all those spaces:

`28 ° 12 ' 37.14 "N
16 ° 39 ' 38.4 "W`

Comment: got it fixed using "+" instead of "," between the values

Comment: Yes, that's what I was saying.  You need to be able to tell the difference between what the values ARE and how you PRINT them.  You could use, for example, an f-string to get it formatted the way you want: `f"{l1[0]}o {l1[1]}'"`

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what the type (class) of the key (I would assume str) or the value (could be str or list?) but in either case there is no need to join them to split them afterwards. The key in a dict must be immutable, the value can literally be any type: mutable or immutable. Do you only wish to print out the lines with co-ords? If so, perhaps you are not extracting the co-ords from a str, but identifying the GPS key-value sets in the dict:

```
import exifread
from selenium import webdriver

with open("pictures/img-1.jpg", "rb") as file:
    tags = exifread.process_file(file)

    for key, value in tags.items():
        if "GPS" in key:
            print(f'{key}: {value}')
```